# If I copy a creature with enters the battlefield ability with sakashima the impostor, does the ability trigger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I copy a creature with enters the battlefield ability with sakashima the impostor, does the ability trigger?
For example, do I gain control of a permanent, if I copy Agent of Treachery. Sakashima retains the name, so if the ability it has says that “when agent of treachery enters…” it seems that the ability should not trigger, as the name is still Sakashima. Does Sakashima replace the name in the text too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do "enters the battlefield" abilities trigger when a creature is copied with Phyrexian Metamorph?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/do-enters-the-battlefield-abilities-trigger-when-a-creature-is-copied-with-phy) - if this doesn't answer the question, please explain why you think Sakashima is different.

Comment: Sakashima is different, because it specifies that it retains the name. If it copies the text verbatim, then the abilities should not trigger, as it is the sakashima that enters, not the agent of treahery.

Comment: In that case, you want [Rayami Mutated has a different name](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50757/rayami-mutated-has-a-different-name) and/or [How does having multiple permanents with the same name affect those permanents' abilities?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/how-does-having-multiple-permanents-with-the-same-name-affect-those-permanents), both of which come down to CR 201.4.